# How to Add Values in existing Object[]

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a `Map<String, Object[]> objMap` and trying to add value in to it. But its not working as expected. My method is as below,

```
public void addInMap(String str, Object... params) {        
        if(params != null && params.length > 0) {
            if(objMap.containsKey(str)) {
                Object[] addedParams= objMap.get(str);
                addedParams[addedParams.length-1]=params;
                objMap.put(str, addedParams);
            }
            else {
                objMap.put(str, params);
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont want to use the `ArrayList` or `Array.asList` .
When i am using `addedParams[addedParams.length]=params` its causing `Attempt to access illegal array index` exception. Where i am doing wrong. With the above code i am not able to add more object its always showing one element in Object[]. Can you please help me to fix this issues.

Comment: In your `addInMap` method create a new array `newParams` with the combined length of `addedParams` and `params`.Then we use `System.arraycopy` to copy the elements of `addedParams` to n`ewParams`. Then loop through the `params` and append values to `newParams`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy of the array with a larger size to allow adding a new element at the end.

```java
addedParams = Arrays.copyOf(addedParams, addedParams.length + 1);
addedParams[addedParams.length - 1] = params;

// or, if you want to merge the two arrays together:
addedParams = Stream.of(addedParams, params).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray();

objMap.put(str, addedParams);
```

But this is quite inefficient. Consider using `ArrayList` instead.